# "As much as" vs "as many as"

Tags: phrase-usage

*As much as* and *as may as* can be used for comparisons.  Looking at other questions with *as much as* or *as many as*, none seem to talk about countability.  I've noticed that

> as much as
>   The water contained in Lake Mille Lacs is *as much as* several lakes combined.
>   He's paid *as much as* his boss.

is used to compare uncountable things, where as

> as many as
>   The number of schools in Minneapolis are *as many as* there are in Oakland.
>   He makes *as many* dollars *as* his boss.

is used for countable things.

But it's not always the case

> Elephants can be *as much as* 10 feet tall if not more.

feet are countable.

> The grains of sand on all the beaches are not *as many as* stars in the sky.

grains of sand are generally considered uncountable.

> All the sand on all the beaches are not *as much as* all the stars in the sky.

also works, but is less specific by not mentioning "grains".

Is there a general rule for using either *as much as* or *as many as*?
Maybe because of the exceptions it's not dependent on countability?

Comment: This is actually a pretty savvy question!  I want to be able to dismiss it with "no, it's just about countability" but you've brought up some good examples.  I would point out that in "Elephants can be as much as..." we're not actually counting feet, like you're counting dollars in "As many dollars as...", you're counting something about elephants...but I'm having trouble explaining exactly what!  Also, *grains of sand* are totally countable.  *Sand* is uncountable (*so much sand!*) but when you add a quantifier like *grains* you make the noun phrase countable (*so many grains of sand!*)

Comment: @stangdon +1 for both you and Peter. Do I misunderstand or is this comment the skeleton of a useful answer? I would like to have this Q&A to point to when this Q is raised again, as it certainly will be.

Comment: @P.E.Dant - I'm trying to grope my way to an answer, but I don't feel like I have a solid one yet.  If I find a good explanation for the elephants example, I'll post an answer.

Comment: @stangdon Exactly. Why the hell wouldn't we say _as **many** as ten feet tall?_ Yet almost every speaker will naturally make with the _much._ Carry on groping. I'm not even at the groping stage yet; just began fumbling.

Comment: I have found one reference: ["Though the number is a count noun, *as much as* means the upper limit of the amount of a non-count noun such as weight, distance, money, price, size, etc."](https://books.google.com/books?id=DXV-AAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA185&dq=%22as%20much%20as%20twenty%22&pg=PA185#v=onepage&q=%22as%20much%20as%20twenty%22&f=false)  I realize that explanation may itself be confusing because "weight" and "distance" and so forth are actually count nouns themselves (weights, distances, etc.) but we use them like non-count nouns (his weight is 150 pounds, not his weights are 150 pounds).

Answer (score 2):

In my understanding using 'as much' or 'as many as' is all about "discreteness". In the case of the elephant, you are measuring its height (size), which is not discrete. The same reasoning applies for the sand grains; the number of sand grains (or stars) have a discrete number (even if we are unable to count them). The weight or volume of sand is not a discrete number like the number of grains are.

@stangdon, weight, distance, and volume are measurable but not countable (not discrete!). I am not sure, but this is my understanding of the "much" and "many" usage.

Answer (score 1):

*As many as* means a number that is equal to another number.(used with countable nouns).
With *not* it means *not equal*.

> The grains of sand on all the beaches are not as many as stars in the sky.
>   Grains of sand are countable.

*As much as* means an amount that is equal to another amount ( used with uncountable nouns).

> All the sand on all the beaches is not as much as all the stars in the sky.
>   *Sand* is uncountable.

*As many as 50, 100* (emphatic ) is used to say how surprisingly large **a number** is.

> As many as 10, 000 people are thought to have fled the area (a number of people).

*As much as 50, 100*(emphatic ) is used to say how surprisingly large **an amount** is. (Longman Exam Dictionary).
With *money, distance, size, time, weight*(they are all uncountable ) we use **as much as**.

> Some machines cost as much as £ 20,000.(money)
>
> Elephants can be as much as 10 feet tall if not more.
>   (height).